# Socket Initialization Failed with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am currently working on a project that requires an android app to connect to a java server that I have created. The problem is that the socket does not initialize. I have added the permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

My app code looks as follows:

Button Trigger:

```
    View.OnClickListener btnDownloadListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Implement download code
        try{
           new ConnectionManager().execute("10.90.181.91" , "21002");
        }catch(Throwable t){

        }

    }
};
```

ConnectionManager Background Function:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    try{
        Log.i("Test", "background thread started");
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
        Socket connSock = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
        Log.i("Test", "Created Socket");

    }catch(Throwable t){

    }

   return "";
}
```

The log is outputting "background Thread Started", but never outputs "Created Socket"

The Server code is as follows:
Main method

```
    try{
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listeningSocket = true;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(21002);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 21002");
        }
        int count = 0;
        while(listeningSocket){             
            try{
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                new ServerThread(clientSocket).start();                 
            }catch(Throwable t){

            }
        }
        System.out.println("You should not be here");
        serverSocket.close();
    }catch(Throwable t){

    }
```

ServerThread

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {

private Socket socket = null;
private String s;
private  InputStream in;
private  OutputStream out;
BufferedReader is;
BufferedWriter os;
public ServerThread(Socket s) {
    socket = s;
    System.out.println("Thread started: " + socket.getInetAddress());
    try{
         in = socket.getInputStream();
         out = socket.getOutputStream();
         out.flush();
         is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
         os = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));

    }catch(Throwable t){
        t.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Thread is running");
    String dataType = "";
    Boolean awaitingTransfer = false;
    try {

        while(true){

            if(in.available() > 0 && !awaitingTransfer){
                dataType = is.readLine();
                System.out.println(dataType);
            }
            if(in.available() > 0 && awaitingTransfer){
                try{
                    ArrayList<SpotCheck> tempList = new ArrayList<SpotCheck>();     
                    while(in.available() > 0){
                        //tempList = (ArrayList<SpotCheck>) in.readObject(); 
                    }

                    ServerMain.manager.applyChanges(tempList);
                    awaitingTransfer = false;
                }catch(Throwable t){
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       try {

        in.close();
        out.close();
           socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should add logging to the catch block of your client and server. And print the normal stack trace there. Add a catch for an IOException. You have a catch so it is already visible in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

As an amateur coder, i just wanted to ask you that, can you just add a toast to the "catch()" blog of your doInBackground like that

```
catch(Exception e)
{
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

      @Override
      public void run(){
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
   });
}
```

so it can show your problem more specifically and it will become easier to handle maybe. but again i am not sure if it works, i mean using toast in asynctask classes is a little bit more tricky.